# replace value in a specific node

Tags: php, xml, replace

I have an XML file and a variable. I want to write a function to replace a specific node's value. Example:

```
write_xml("->system_settings->settings->hostname",'Helloooooooo');

function write_xml($tag_address, $value) {

    $xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml")
                 or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    $xml->system_settings->settings->hostname = $value;

    $xml->asXML("test.xml");
}
```

In this example, the node `->system_settings->settings` if `helloooooo` should be replaced with `hostname`.

My problem is: in the above code, I entered the path manually and it works. But if I assign my path dynamically (like below), it doesn't work:

```
write_xml("->system_settings->settings->hostname",'Helloooooooo');

function write_xml($tag_address, $value) {

    ...
    $xml->$tag_address = $value; // <---- doesn't work
    $xml->asXML("test.xml");
}
```

What should i do?

Comment: show a snippet of your XML, please, by editing your question.

Comment: pass only system_settings->settings->hostname and then use it with the sign ->$firstValue